# Why isn't the cd command working in my shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, cd

I'm trying to run my first script, just a simple cd reroute.[this is the what my file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvuVc.jpg)

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work. the script is basically

```
#!bin/bash
echo "moving you to Desktop"
cd /mnt/c/Users/duanj/Desktop
echo "finished moving"
```

and both the echo statements end up printing. But no redirect.
Also, when I type the cd command in verbatim into my terminal it works.

Comment: why do you think `cd` is not working? , try `cd /mnt/c/Users/duanj/Desktop && echo "cd worked"  || echo "cd failed"`

Comment: what do those additions do?

Comment: @thejhndwn : I hope you are aware that the working directory is a local property of the process. If you would write `echo "finished moving to $PWD", you would see that PWD has changed; but of course in your calling (parent) process, the working directory is still the same. But if you run your script inside your current process, i.e. by `source SCRIPTNAME`, you avoid creating a child process and the working directory will change in your shell.